# Switching domain based on SSL MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am not sure whether this can be acheived in code or if this rule needs to be applied within ISS.

Basically I have three domains:

```
domain1.co.uk > redirects to .com
domain1.com > Primary domain registered with SSL
domain1.ie > I want to redirect this to .com based on SSL request
```

I have configured my MVC app to display relative content based on the domain. So if the request comes in from a .ie address then I can then display relevant content/Meta data etc.  However my issue is that when I visit /Account/Login under HTTPS I get an SSL error as the certificate is registered under the .com domain.

I would really like to keep the .ie binding for the HTTP static site and index this on Google but as soon as the user tries to navigate to a HTTPS I would like to switch to the .com domain.

I appreciate I can do this by changing the links throughout the site and I have also tried the below with no avail:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if(Context.Request.IsSecureConnection && Context.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("domain1.ie"))
            Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("domain1.ie", "domain1.com"));
    }
```

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

To allow the IIS webserver to respond to SSL requests for different domains, you will need to enable [server name indicator](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability) on the server to allow you to serve SSL content using two different certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URL Rewriter](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite):

Something like:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="ON" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain1.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

With your shared code base, you may want to tweek the match rule so it only fires for IE.

But you would need to configure the server to use SSL on two sites, either by using a [SAN Certificate](https://opensrs.com/blog/2012/09/san-and-wildcard-certificates-whats-the-difference/) or by having multiple IPs bound to the box's nic to handle the multiple https requests.